# I need to re-arrange data in Excelsheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an Excel table similar to the one below.

Table:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gP35L.png]

The data i have is similar but i have ~350 entries.

My question is, how can i easily transfer the data from the top row to the corresponding row (marked with 1 in the table)? Meaning that where there is a "1" against a name, i would have to swap it with the corresponding date from the top row.

I can do this manually, but having in mind that there are more than 300 entries, it would take a lot of time.

Example on how it should look like:

Final result:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4MF5b.png]

Thank you!

Martin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments made by @MartinPetrov under @Napoli's answer, the OP wants to to group the dates next to each name, maybe in one of the following way:

[image: Examples]

This can be done using `#powerquery` which is a built-in function of Excel. Please refer to this [article](https://www.excelcampus.com/install-power-query/) to find out how to use **Power Query** on your version of Excel. It is available in **Excel 2010 Professional Plus and later versions**. My demonstration is using **Excel 2016**.

I used the following table called **Tbl_10X10** which is a `10 x 10` table based on the original table provided by OP with some sample data highlighted in yellow. This solution is working for 350x350 or even larger data set.

[image: Source Data]

The steps are:

1. Load the source data to **power query editor** which should look like the following:

[image: Loaded]

2. Use **Unpivot Columns** function under the `Transform` tab to unpivot all columns except the first one, and then **remover** the `Value` column, then you should have the following:

[image: Unpivoted]

3. Use **Group By** function under the `Transform` tab to group `Attribute` column by `Column1` as set out below. Don't panic if the result is in `error` as it is expected.

[image: Grouped By]

4. Go back to last step and replace the original formula in the formula bar with the following one as **Text.Combine** is not a built-in function:

[image: Text Combine]

Here is the formula: `= Table.Group(#"Removed Columns", {"Column1"}, {{"Sum", each Text.Combine([Attribute], " ; "), type text}})`

If you are happy to have all dates grouped in one column, then our query will stop here. If you want them to be in separate columns, you can use **Split Column** function under the `Transform` tab to split the dates into separate columns as shown below:

[image: Splited]

> Please note I put in `10` as the number of columns to split into. In your case you may want to put in `350` or a reasonable number to ensure all dates can be put into a column, and then bulk remove columns with `null` value in them.

Once done, you can **Close & Load** the query to a new worksheet (by default).

Here are the Power Query **M codes** behind the scene. Most steps are using built-in functions which are straight forward except the last step of overwriting the formula in the formula bar.

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Tbl_10X10"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}, {"September, 12", Int64.Type}, {"June, 13", Int64.Type}, {"August, 21", Int64.Type}, {"July, 5", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Unpivoted Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type", {"Column1"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Unpivoted Columns",{"Value"}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Removed Columns", {"Column1"}, {{"Sum", each Text.Combine([Attribute], " ; "), type text}}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Sum", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(";", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"Sum.1", "Sum.2", "Sum.3", "Sum.4", "Sum.5", "Sum.6", "Sum.7", "Sum.8", "Sum.9", "Sum.10"}),
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{"Sum.7", "Sum.8", "Sum.9", "Sum.10"})
in
    #"Removed Columns1"
```

Let me know if you have any questions. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

You could copy your list of 350 records, and paste them into a tangent column.
Next, you can use the formula `=IF(B2>=1,B$1,"")` and drag/apply that to all your cells.

See my screenshot below.

[image]

Below is my excel document with the formulas shown.

[image]

Comment: I have a quick follow up question. Do you know how i can transfer all the dates to 1 column, next to the first one (containing all the names)?

Comment: do you mean consolidating the four columns into one column? you could do a nested `IF` ... like..`=IF(LEN(H2)>0,H2,IF(LEN(I2)>0,I2,IF(LEN(J2)>0,J2,IF(LEN(K2)>0,K2,""))))` and drag that formula down

Comment: Yeah, that would work. But how do i do that to 350 rows? I have 350 columns and rows. :/

Comment: 350 columns?? are you sure? to consolidate 350 columns some additional work would be needed.

Comment: Yep, it is basically 350x350. And there is only one "1" entry per name. So the first part works perfect - swapping the "1" with the corresponding date, but there is no shortcut for consolidating all to 1 column? You did save me some time with the first part, so i might do  the second part manually. :)

Comment: with that many columns, you'll either need to write some VBScript to make the changes, or, there's an add-on you can install which should merge as needed. it's called `Ablebits`; it has an advanced "Merge Cells", which should do what you need.